# access_token given by Oauth2 procedure is not authorized for accessing Orion FI-LAB

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

The oauth2 procedure that we used to get the access token for accessing Orion FI-LAB instance provided at https://github.com/fgalan/oauth2-example-orion-client does not work anymore.
something has happened since 10 days ago.
we have used the same procedure for retrieving the token in our android application.now either our android app dose not work.

**The probblem is :**

The access token generated by the server.js code is not recognized as a valid X-Auth-Token for the orion FI-LAB instance (orion.lab.fi-ware.eu:1026).
by running the sample we get the below response

```
 {
   "access_token": "3ujlcoB3uUCy45ZasN5c89DoV9549d",
   "expires_in": 3600,
   "token_type": "Bearer",
   "state": "xyz",
   "scope": "all_info",
   "refresh_token": "FrmaTmGCJ4DDKkeGlWxfERB6R3jtij"
 }
```

However, when we use the above access_token for making http request to orion context broker we get this answer: "User token not authorized".

On the other hand, the token obtained by the token_script.sh shell  works well as X-Auth-Token for the orion FI-LAB instance.

**The question**

which way is going to be the stable approach to access the FI-LAB Orion instance:

- the procedure taken by the **server.js**(in which the given token is not working)
  or
- the procedure taken by **token_script.sh**
  ?

Comment: This "unstability" is a consencuence of a recent migration of some FIWARE Lab components related with security (such as the IdM). We are working on it and we hope to provide an answer to your question soon.

Comment: Dear fgalan,we have fixed the bug in (https://github.com/fgalan/oauth2-example-orion-client)  line 134 of oauth2.js file,by just adding the below line.  'Content-Length' : Buffer.byteLength(post_data) .However, even with this fix the generated access tokens is  not authorized.

Comment: We have been doing some changes to the auth framework this morning. Could you try again in order to see if is still failing, please?

Comment: The appropriate approach to get the token in the global instance is the one for the 'token_script.sh' script. I've just tested it with a query to the global instance and it seems to work fine for my user, so, maybe the problem is not in the way you access but in the user itself. I think (but the IDM team should confirm this) that passwords were reset when the migration took place. Did you recover the password? Are you able to access with your user and password to the Filab server: https://account.lab.fiware.org/?

Comment: Concerning the 'server.js' file, I've been testing it, and I had some problems due to an ill-configured idmURL parameter. Please, check that you are using 'https://account.lab.fiware.org' as the IDM url.

Comment: @ShimaFahima, we have introduced some fixes in the last version of server.js. Could you download it (githash: 49d9c416b43ecac8971379833b7b4f4b5d3016e3) and test again, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be due to different reasons:

- IDM password reseting during the FIWARE Lab migration on May 2015
- Some bugs in the server.js script (some of them also related with changes in the security system after migration), currently fixed (githash: 49d9c416b43ecac8971379833b7b4f4b5d3016e3)

Comment: Please, mark the answer as valid so other users can know it. Thanks!